# radmin behaving as if my shift key is pressed down

Tags: keyboard, remote-access

I am using radmin 2.2 to connect to other PC's on  my  network, I have a problem when I remote access other users on my internal network, and  I  try to type a number, I am getting characters instead. such as "!" instead of "1" , "@"  instead of "2", "#"   instead of "3" and "$" instead of "4".  The app is behaving as if my shift key is permanantly pressed down (which it is not).  Pleased advise what I should do in order to fix this problem.   I dont have this problem when I am sitting in front of the computer or when I use logmein in the same PC
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the status of the Shift, Control, and Alt keys can be left lingering when switching between programs that take over the keyboard (this can be seen more frequently with PC virtualization through applications like VirtualBox.org).

But the good news is that the solution is a very simple one:

Tap each Shift key once (left and right shift keys are handled as separate keys).  Do the same thing with your Alt and CTRL keys.  Just press them separately each one at a time, and then all should be well after that.

Comment: +1: This has driven me nuts since at least Windows 2000. As you suggest I usually just slam Ctrl-Atl-Shift a couple times and it 'fixes' itself. ;)